# What are the rudimentary types of information connectivity i.e. model types?

Tags: data-structures, information-theory, modelling, structured-data

I am looking at a modelling tool and are trying to determine all the types of ways that you can model (at a rudimentary level)

I remember seeing a list of ways in which you can connect or categorise information elements. basically the types were as follows:

- Lists - constitute a list of information elements
- Hierarchies- visualise information in a parent-child relationship (ie organisational chart)
- Flows - connect elements in a logical (lateral) flow (ie process model)

  Have you seen any reference to these types, or can you elaborate on the full list of "model types"

Answer (score 6):

[Model theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory), branch of mathematical logic, is based on three things: atoms, functions, and relations. With these you can define pretty much anything. In fact, functions are subsumed by relations, so you only need two.

What is a list but a *next* relation? What is a hierarchy but a parent-child relation?

Of course these satisfy axioms, and these can readily be expressed in first order logic.

Comment: Ok, i see your point, closely related would be the semantic web's OWL standard depicting classes, properties and relationships, however i would like to categorise the visual structures of those classes into a basic list of visualisation types (ie, non-related classes can only be represented in a list), classes relating in a parent-child manner would best be demonstrated using a hierarchy model...etc